# Глобальная переменная своего типа - c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Завожу глобальную переменную собственноручно написанного класса в файле main.cpp следующим образом:

```
extern Next temp;
```

И определяю её в нужных мне h-файлах:

```
Next temp;
```

Компилятор жалуется:

```
 Ошибка C2146   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "temp"  
 Ошибка C4430   отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
```

таких ошибок много.
Прошу помощи.
P.S.: так с любым моим классом.
P.S.S.: да, я в курсе, глобальные переменные зло. Но тут она требуется. Отвечу сразу, для чего. Для использование я оконной процедуре WndProc, которая находится в **другом файле.**

Минимальный(!!!) пример:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "d3dUtility.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
using namespace d3d;
D3DXDevice dxDevice;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**d3dUtility.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include "function.h"

namespace d3d
{
    class D3DXDevice
    {
        IDirect3DDevice9* Device; // указатель на созданное устройство
    public:
        D3DXDevice();
        IDirect3DDevice9* getDevice();
        ~D3DXDevice();
    };
};
```

**d3dUtility.cpp**

```
#include "d3dUtility.h"

namespace d3d
{
    D3DXDevice::D3DXDevice() :Device(nullptr) {}

    IDirect3DDevice9 * D3DXDevice::getDevice()
    {
        return this->Device;
    }

    D3DXDevice::~D3DXDevice()
    {
        this->Device->Release(); // удаляем устройство
    }

};
```

**function.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "d3dUtility.h"
#include <windows.h>

using namespace d3d;

extern D3DXDevice dxDevice;
bool Display();
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "function.h"

bool Display() 
{
    if (dxDevice.getDevice()) 
    {
        dxDevice.getDevice()->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, 5, 1.0f, 0); 

        dxDevice.getDevice()->Present(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    }
    return true; 
}
```

P.S.: увы, но это правда минимальный пример.
P.S.S.: VS 2017.

Comment: Сложно сказать, что у вас не так. Нужен полный пример кода. Выпилите все лишнее, чтобы остался минимум кода, но воспроизводящий ошибку. И добавьте в текст вопроса.

Comment: Один момент....

Comment: @Voidificator готово.

Comment: Какой конкретно cpp-шник компилится, когда возникает ошибка?

Comment: @Voidificator извините, студия обманула меня - этот пример рабочий. Сейчас скорректирую немного.

Comment: @Voidificator код изменён. Ошибки сыпятся на всё: и на cpp, и на h. Честно говоря, первый раз вижу такое.

Comment: Еще момент. После скобочки }, закрывающей пространство имен (d3d), точка с запятой не ставится.

Comment: @Abyx таки да, буду знать...только вопрос, почему нельзя? Ошибка с пространстовом имён ушла

Comment: @Voidificator это чистая случайность. Но ситуацию это не исправило..

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы не подключили хедер с определением `Next`. Только что собрал и выполнил аналогичный пример.

Comment: @andy.37 я прикреплял ниже минимальный воспроизводящий пример, вроде бы все заинклюдено(могу ошибаться) но ошика всё та же.

Comment: В примере попросту нет переменной `temp`, поэтому на него полагаться не стоит, там не может быть такой ошибки

Comment: @andy.37 можете собрать пример - именно на нём такая ошибка. Переменная для наблюдения: dxDevice

Comment: @andy.37 http://i-fotki.info/23/7d223e1042137b61d50bd701405543116dac37290339622.png.html

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t57wswcs.aspx - ошибка С2872. Попробуйте убрать `using namespace...` из хедера.

Comment: @Abyx здесь явно не обойтись одной единицей, учитывая `extern`

Comment: @andy.37 уже убрал, выше был совет. Помогло, но только с парой ошибок, к посту не относятся..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут вот какое дело, если я правильно понял текст программы. В файле d3dUtility.h Вы подключаете файл function.h, в котором объявлена внешняя переменная. Но дело в том, что на этот момент класс еще даже не объявлен. Отсюда и ошибка. Выход: не включать сюда function.h либо делать опережающее объявление класса D3DXDevice.

Comment: В `function.h` включен нужный хедер с объявлением класса.

Comment: Убрал включение function.h - не сработало, жалобы остались..

Comment: ага, и что получаем? рекурсивное включение файла? Вообще странно - я убрал включение function.h - и мой g++ это собрал без проблем.

Comment: @Vladimir уточню. Убрано включение function.h из d3dutility.h
Студия не завелась

Comment: именно из него, да

Comment: @Vladimir глухо, однако..

Comment: а ошибка все та же осталась? не может ли быть проблем еще в поддержке стандартов у VC++? В g++ мне собирает с C++11 и не собирает с C++03...

Comment: Ошибка та же,но меньше. ну со стандартами..если я просто заведу примитивный класс. и сделаю такую же ситуацию - ошибка останется.

Comment: Если пока избавиться от пространств имен (закомментировать все d3d) и добавить упреждающее объявление класса в файл function.h:  class D3DXDevice; (перед объявлением переменной dxDevice), то тоже все собирается. А вот как делать корректно упреждающее объявление класса с пространствами имен - я не знаю..

Comment: @Vladimir действительно, воспользовавшись Вашим советом - всё собралось..Как же это объяснить?

Comment: Пространства имен добавляют сложности при таких объявлениях и моих знаний тут не хватает (чтобы бороться со всем этим вместе). И боюсь, тут еще MS добавило от себя некорректную реализацию стандарта. Что же касается классов без пространства имен, то все в моем ответе: компилятору для сборки нужно знать хотя бы то, что это класс и что он где-то объявлен. И еще у Вас получаются рекурсивные включения файла d3dUtility.h в самого себя через function.h (тут pragma once помогает как бы... и портит объявление).

Comment: @Vladimir огромное Вам спасибо! Всё, проект заведён, всё работает. Сколько тонкостей..буду учитывать в следующий раз. :)